# Ubuntu client can't mount Nexenta NFS

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, solaris, zfs, nexenta

I have a Nexenta storage box (Solaris), which exports an NFS share.
Mac OS X and older Ubuntu clients can mount the NFS share just fine without any special options. Later version of Ubuntu simply returns:

> mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 10.0.0.10:/volumes/Shares/share

From the Nexenta logs it doesn't seem like Ubuntu is even trying to communicate and the logs on the Ubuntu client is also empty.

The Nexenta is configured to NFSv3 only.
My fstab entry is:

> 10.0.0.10:/volumes/Shares/share/   /mnt/images/    nfs vers=3,rw,nodev,nosuid,noexec

Is there something I need to consider when mounting Solaris/Nexenta NFS shares from Linux?

Comment: What are your permissions on the NFS share? Is this full NexentaStor? If you have access to the GUI, it should be easy to determine what your share's permissions are.

Comment: Cold it be the firewall?

Comment: new linux clients are using nfsv4 by default. Did you try with explicit '-o vers=3'?

Answer (score 1):

Questions like firewalls are good things to check. Once you are sure the machines can talk to eachother, I found that I needed to set some access control in ZFS:

zfs set share=name=tank,path=/tank,prot=nfs,nosuid=true,sec=sys,rw=@10.0.0.1/24,root=@10.0.0.1/24 tank

Try that and see if you can get them talking.